# create logging service with nlog

Tags: logging, nlog

I am trying to create a .net logging web service with nlog, the purpose is to create universal logging platform handle all the applications' errors. I plan to start with web api project, is there any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like NLog is smallest part in this adventure. Any reason you don't use Kibana / ElasticSearch ? (Or some of other existing log-collection solutions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some targets in NLog which support webservices/apis, see https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=targets&search=web

Another option is to create a custom target (see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target) that will send all the logs to you universal logging service.

Depending on your volume, I could be wise to send the events in batches, instead of a webservice call per event.